# Declaration never used - but it is?

Tags: scala, for-loop

I am writing in Scala and within this *if* statement I have a *for* loop and I initialized *i=0* and used *i* in the *for* loop. It is telling me that declaration is not used, but I am using it in the *for* loop. *top* is always equal to 5 also.

```
else {
    var i = 0
    for (i <- 0 until (top))
```

Comment: You are creating a new `val` `i` i  the `for` you don't need to initialize a variable for a `for` in **Scala**... It is actually not even a loop like in other languages. - I recommend you to pick a tutorial or something to learn the language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For loops work a little different in Scala than other languages. In Scala, a `for` comprehension is syntax sugar over `foreach`, `filter`, `map`/`flatMap` [higher order functions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html).

When you write

```
for (i <- 0 until top)
```

The compiler re-writes this to

```
(0 until top).foreach {
  i => ...
}
```

Here, the `foreach` body is an [anonymous function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/anonymous-functions.html) where `i` is the function parameter that has the same type as the iterable. So you can just remove the declaration for `i` in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Like posted before, the `for` in Scala is a [very different animal than in e.g. Java](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html). Using it as an iterator is only one of its many potential usages.
For your code: The first and the second `i` are not the same. In fact, the variable in the `for` expression is ephemeral and doesn't leave the `for`'s scope, but actually [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer one.

```scala
var i = 0 // you don't need this
for (i <- 0 until (top)) // loops from 0 to whatever top is regardless what's in the outer i
```

This will print `0 1 2 3 4`:

```scala
val top = 5
for (i <- 0 until (top)) {
  println(i)
}
```

One really cool aspect of `for` comes from the `yield` keyword (example from the first link):

```scala
val names = List("adam", "david", "frank")
val ucNames = for (name <- names) yield name.capitalize
```

Also it is used to kind of map over multiple collections/monads etc. at once like in Haskell, a task rather tedious otherwise:

```scala
val names = List("adam", "david")
val numbers = List(1, 2)
val lst = for {
  name <- names
  number <- numbers
} yield s"$name: $number"
```

`lst` will now hold the cartesian product of the two lists as a `List[String]`: `List("adam: 1", "adam: 2", "david: 1", "david: 2")`